# Ломается график при построении касательной к графику функции

Tags: python, математика, matplotlib, график

Почему при построении наклонной прямой график функции ломается (изменяется масштабирование по оси `Y`) ?

```
def f(x):
    return (x/(x-1)**2)**(1/3)

def y(x, k, b):
    return x * k + b

x0 = 1.9 
y0 = f(x0)

dF = sp.diff(f(x), x)
d2F = sp.diff(f(x), x, 2)
k = dF.evalf(subs={x:x0})
b = f(x0) - k * x0

x_List = np.arange(a, a1, h)
x_List[(x_List>=-0.1) & (x_List<0.1)] = np.nan
f_List = [f(x) for x in x_List]

x2_List = np.arange(a, a1, h)
y_List = [y(x, k, b) for x in x2_List]

lineF = plt.plot(x_List, f_List, linewidth=2.0)
line_tangent = plt.plot(x2_List, y_List, linewidth=1.0)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит «ломается»?

Comment: То есть, график функции немного укорачивается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [plt.ylim()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) чтобы явно задать пределы значений по оси Y:

```
plt.ylim(-1, 5)
```